# Filter and updating elements of array in go language with mongo

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm going to update the existing elements of the array, not just override all elements. Assume that it has a users list that collects device names and tokens.
For example:

```
{
"id": SOME_GENERATED_ID,
"uid": SOME_UUID,
"tokens": [
   {
     "deviceName": "web",
     "token": "your first web token"
   },
   {
     "deviceName": "android",
     "token": "your first android token"
   }
]
}
```

Here, I did it on MongoDB shell which works exactly what I wanted it.

```
db.users.updateOne(
{},
{ $set: { "tokens.$[elem].deviceName" : "web", "tokens.$[elem].token" : "your web's updated token" } },
{ arrayFilters: [ { "elem.deviceName": { $eq: "web" } } ] }
)
```

which updates only web tokens.
But in the go language, it doesn't update the exact elements, it is overwriting the entire array.

Here is what I did in go language.

```
col := n.mongo.Database("fcm_db").Collection("users")
    filter := bson.M{"uuid": user.UUID}
    arrayFilters := options.ArrayFilters{
        //Filters: []interface{}{bson.M{"x.deviceName": user.Tokens[0].DeviceName}},
        Filters: bson.A{bson.M{"x.deviceName": bson.M{"$eq": user.Tokens[0].DeviceName}}},
    }
    update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "tokens.$[x].deviceName": user.Tokens[0].DeviceName,
            "tokens.$[x].token":      user.Tokens[0].Token,
        },
    }
    opts := options.UpdateOptions{
        ArrayFilters: &arrayFilters,
        //Upsert:       &upsert,
    }

    ret, err := col.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update, &opts)
    if err != nil {
        n.logger.Error(err.Error())
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("result UpsertedCount %v", ret.UpsertedCount)
    fmt.Printf("result ModifiedCount %v", ret.ModifiedCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB update:

```
db.collection.update(
    {}, 
    { $set: { "tokens.$[e].token": "updated value" }},
    { arrayFilters: [ { "e.deviceName": "web" } ] }
)
```

The Golang code:

```
filter := bson.D{{}}
update := bson.D{{ "$set", bson.D{{ "tokens.$[e].token", "updated value" }}}}
arrayFiltersOpt := options.ArrayFilters{ Filters: []interface{}{ bson.D{{ "e.deviceName", "web" }} }}
opts := options.Update().SetArrayFilters(arrayFiltersOpt)

updateResult, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update, opts)
```